# How to use fold method of StringOps in Scala?

Tags: scala

I tried to calculate the product of the unicode of the String "Hello" in scala. And in the StringOps scala API, I found the method fold and foldLeft and I wrote some code by using the above 2 methods:

```
val s = "Hello"
s.fold(1L){(z, i) => z*i}
s.foldLeft(1L){(z, i) => z*i}
```

By using the 2nd expression, I can get the correct answer, but the first cannot and the IDE complains "cannot resolve symbol *", anybody can explain this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the type signature of `fold`:

```
fold[A1 >: Char](z: A1)(op: (A1, A1) ⇒ A1): A1
```

you'll see that it only operates on supertypes of `Char`s, therefore making your expression impossible and the compiler throwing an error.

`foldLeft` however allows you to use a result type `B`

```
foldLeft[B](z: B)(op: (B, Char) ⇒ B): B
```

This allows you to write your current expression.

To recap: `fold` expects a `Char` as its seed argument (when you provide `1L` as your seed the compiler will complain), while `foldLeft` expects the resulting type of your `op` function.

**Update:**

`s.fold(1L){(z, i) => z}` is also deemed correct by the compiler. This is because `Char` and `Long` share the supertype `AnyVal`. Since `fold` expects a supertype of `Char` providing an `AnyVal` also works. This is also the reason why the compiler complains that it can't find the function `*`, because it is not defined on type `AnyVal`.

**Update 2:**

If you really want to use `fold` instead of `foldLeft` you will have to map `s` to a Seq[Long] beforehand. I.e.:

```
s.map(_.toLong).fold(1L){(z, i) => z*i} //returns 9415087488
```

Comment: can you please give me an example?But as I test, the expression s.fold(1L){(z, i) => z} is also correct, and the seed is 1L, and not char, why it is also right?

Comment: What kind of example would you like to see?

Comment: When I provide 1L as my seed the compiler did not complain, and the result is 1

Comment: How can calculate the product of the unicode of the String "Hello"  by fold please?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to calculate the correct product by using `fold`. What's the problem with using `foldLeft` instead?

Comment: It seems that the Long 1L is converted to AnyVal implicitly. But the expr s.fold(""){(z, i) => z + ":" + i }, this works, and the seed is a String, why it has the operator '+' please?

Comment: The `+` operator in that expression comes from the `implicit class any2stringadd` which allows just about anything to be added to a String.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135092/discussion-between-coinnigh-and-luka-jacobowitz).